# What are some advantages of using binary I/O in place of text I/O?

Tags: java

could someone please tell me some advantages of using binary I/O in place of text I/O.

i'm not sure why it would be better to use binary I/O over text I/O.

Comment: Do you **really** mean binary vs. text I/O, i.e. which mode you set when opening the file? Or do you mean "data that looks like a bunch of nonsense but is actually densely packed with useful information" vs "data that I can open in a word processor as plain text and read", like people usually really mean when they ask this?

Answer (score 5):

You use binary I/O when you're reading/writing binary data (like an image or sound), and you use text I/O when you're reading/writing text (like... text). It's not a matter of advantages or disadvantages, it's using the appropriate tool.

Comment: Sort of like the advantage of brushing your teeth versus combing your hair :-)

Answer (score 2):

In a sense, all data is stored as binary (bits of one and zeros).

But if you mean could it make more sense to store, say, 12,345 as text ("12,345") vs. binary (the value 12,345), the answer is yes.

In this example, binary uses less memory and can be read and written faster because it doesn't need to be parsed and translated back to a numeric value (int, long, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Though this comparision would really help: http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/csbsju/cs/160/notes/34/0.html